# How to distinguish between a @string and @@string?

Tags: php, regex, string, text

Given a string

```
$str="hello @jake and @@tim_24 and @@mike and @frank1 and @@ali_gi and @tom";
```

Is it possible to extract all usernames beginning by `@` only in `one array` and all usernames beginning by `@@` in a `second array`?

This is what I've tried so far,

```
preg_match_all('~@([^\s]+)~', $str, $array);
print_r($array[0]);
```

Problem with this is that it gets every username (begining with `@` or `@@`) in one array `$array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this,

```
\B@@(\w+)|\B@(\w+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fT9eG2/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like so: `(?<!@)@([^@\s]+)` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/wN6tI9/2)).

The matched names will be placed in group 1.